# Calculating the overlap distance of two 1D line segments

Tags: python, geometry

Trying to build a function that will return the total overlapping distance between 2 line segments, denoted by start and end ints.

Currently I have this: That I got off the internet somewhere,

```
def overlap(min1, max1, min2, max2):
    """returns the overlap between two lines that are 1D"""
    result = None
    if min1 >= max2 or min2 >= max1: result =  0
    elif min1 <= min2:
        result = max1 - min2
    else: result = max2 - min1
    return result
```

This works however for the case of 0 100, 0,20 it returns 100. And that's clearly wrong.
Is there a simple way of calculating this that will return the correct values?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
def overlap(min1, max1, min2, max2):
    return max(0, min(max1, max2) - max(min1, min2))

>>> overlap(0, 10, 80, 90)
0
>>> overlap(0, 50, 40, 90)
10
>>> overlap(0, 50, 40, 45)
5
>>> overlap(0, 100, 0, 20)
20
```

Comment: I like such a simple answer.

Answer (score 6):

Not fully tested, but how about -

```
def overlap(min1,max1,min2,max2):
    start = max(min1,min2)
    end = min(max1,max2)
    d = end - start
    if d < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return d

#some tests
print overlap(0,100,0,20)
print overlap(5,10,15,20)
print overlap(1,3,0,5)
print overlap(-5,5,-2,10)

>>> 
20
0
2
7
```

Answer (score 1):

In 1-D the premise of checking for overlaps is simple (I think). Find the bigger of the `minimum` values and the smaller of the `maximum` values. Then subtract the two.

```
def overlap(min1, max1, min2, max2):
    #Find out the bigger minimum
    if min1 >= min2: 
        bigger_min = min1
    else: 
        bigger_min = min2
    if max1 >= max2: 
        smaller_max = max2
    else: 
        smaller_max = max1
    if smaller_max <= bigger_min: 
        return 0
    else: 
        return smaller_max - bigger_min
```

Results

```
>>> overlap(20,40,30,70)
10
>>> overlap(0,100,200,300)
0
>>> overlap(0,100,0,30)
30
>>> overlap(0,100,30,60)
30
>>> overlap(0,100,30,70)
40
>>> overlap(20,100,30,70)
40
>>> overlap(20,30,30,70)
0
>>> overlap(0,50,0,50)
50
```