# Reduce this loop to an equation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, strength-reduction

This function (written in C for convenience, but this is not important to the question) determines the size of an array.  I'm sure it can be converted to an if-else chain or even to an equation, but I am not clever enough to see how.  (I tried to write down the obvious if-else chain but got bogged down in cases.)

```
// 0 <= from <= 0x10FFFF
// 1 <= len <= 0x10FFFF
unsigned int size_for_block(unsigned int from, unsigned int len)
{
  unsigned int size = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    unsigned int point = from + i;
    if (0xD800 <= point && point <= 0xDFFF)
      ;
    else if (point <= 0xFFFF)
      size += 1;
    else
      size += 2;
  }
  return size;
}
```

If there is a general, idiotproof technique for converting this kind of loop to arithmetic, that would be an ideal answer.  Failing that, the solution for this instance would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By combining nmclean's answer and the concept from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691524/calculating-the-overlap-distance-of-two-1d-line-segments), I now have this:

```
function overlap(min1, max1, min2, max2) {
  return Math.max(0, Math.min(max1, max2) - Math.max(min1, min2));
}
size = (overlap(from, from+len, 0x000000, 0x00D800) +
        overlap(from, from+len, 0x00E000, 0x010000) +
        overlap(from, from+len, 0x010000, 0x110000)*2);
```

which I have exhaustively tested to always produce the same results as the original, and which clearly shows how to do this sort of thing in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

First, for simplicity:

```
to = from + len - 1
```

I think it could be broken into 3 equations, for each "section". That is:

- A: `0` to `0xD800 - 1`
- B: `0xD800` to `0xDFFF`
- C: `0xDFFF + 1` to infinity

Section *A* and *C* are "worth" 2, and *B* is worth 1. Unless I have misinterpreted your code -- is there only 2 sections?

So multiply each section value by the length of the range that falls within it:

**A:** `if (from < 0xD800) size += 2 * min((0xD800 - 1) - from + 1, len)`

Assuming `min` is a function that returns the lesser of its arguments: The range is *"`from` to the end of the section, or `len`, whichever is shorter"*. Range is (end - start + 1).

**B:** `if (to > 0xD800) size += 1 * min(0xDFFF - 0xD800 + 1, to - D800 + 1)`

The logic is similar here: *"the full section, or the beginning of the section to `to`, whichever is shorter"*.

**C:** `if (to > 0xDFFF + 1) size += 2 * (to - (0xDFFF + 1) + 1)`

This is simpler because there is no end point: just count from the beginning to `to`.

I have no idea if this would be more efficient for a computer. It's definitely less efficient for my brain, though.

Comment: There are actually *four* regions: 0 to 0xD7FF, D800 to DFFF, E000 to FFFF, and 10000 on up, worth 1, 0, 1, and 2 respectively.  I like the *idea* here, but the additional region makes it messier than I am entirely happy with.  This is part of an automated test, and the test is too slow, which is why I was trying to optimize it, but I could be persuaded that it's easier to understand the way it is and that's more important...